# Check GraphVIZ installed on windows

Tags: graphviz

How to check version and path of GraphViz installed on Windows? What command on command prompt is used or Registry location to find them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run "dot -V" from the command prompt. If GraphViz is installed and configured you'll get it's version.